# nodejs-express - Implement Redis caching over main database as mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, redis

I have a simple API with basic `CRUD operations` where a User can have multiple Tasks and once user logged in can Update, Delete, Add and Fetch all the tasks. 
I am using `MongoDB` with `mLab` as my main data store to store documents for User and Task Schemas.
I want to implement `Redis caching` in my app(Just for learning purposes) and a use case I can think of is to implement it when I fetch tasks for a particular user(on Homepage) when he logs in as that `getAllUserTasks` is very often used and called when there is any Delete/Update/Add happens.
As of now, the app works fine with `MongoDB` and documents are getting properly reflected in `mLab`.
Now coming to Redis part, I have a query that how should I structure my Redis Database. First, let me post what I have in my App so far :

User Schema :

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  userName: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  hashPassword: { type: String, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  userAge: { type: Number, required: true },
  userDetails: { type: String, required: true },
  userCreatedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Task Schema :

```
const taskSchema = new Schema({
  //Below is userAssigned which is ref for above User document.
  userAssigned: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: User},
  taskDesc: { type: String, required: true },
  taskCreatedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  taskDueDate: { type: Date, required: true }
});
```

getAllUserTasks function:

```
async function getAllUserTasks(userParam) {
  return await Task.find({ userAssigned: userParam.userId })
    .lean()
    .sort({ taskDueDate: "asc" });
}
```

Now `getAllUserTasks` returns me an `Array` of all the tasks for the User. 
I googled a bit and found that I can use `https://redislabs.com/` for my Redis Database. Now how should I structure my Redis database to fetch tasks performantly? 1.  Should I just copy the above schema to Redis database and my tasks documents will live over there.
2.  Should I have a `key` like 'Tasks' and a `value` will be an Array of Tasks that I am getting from .find in the `getAllUserTasks` call. If that's the case how will I make sure that once tasks are Deleted/Updated/Added the Redis Database will be updated accordingly? Just for reference below are my Update/Create/Delete methods :

createTask

```
async function createTask(userParam) {
  if (await User.findOne({ _id: userParam.userAssigned })) {
    const task = new Task(userParam);
    await task.save();
  } else {
    throw "User does not exist";
  }
}
```

updateTask

```
async function updateTask(id, userParam) {
  return await Task.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    userParam,
    {
      new: true,
      overwrite: true
    },
    function(err) {
      if (err) return err;
    }
  );
}
```

deleteUserTask

```
async function deleteUserTask(id) {
  return await Task.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
  });
}
```

As I am new to Redis any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to store all data to redis. Cache is kind of shortcut. It is good if there is a data, but it does not matter if there is not.

Store tasks when `getAllUserTasks` is called. Key can be user id. Value can be array of task having id for identity.

If someone's tasks are mutated, just clear someone's tasks from redis.

```js
getAllUserTasks(param) {
  1. Find tasks from redis by user key.
  2. If they exist, return them.
  3. If not, get data from db and store them to redis.
  4. Return data.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got an idea of how to do this. I used redislabs and seems to be working fine now :)